# Recyclerview - Loading all items without scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll

So I have a cart like this. The total cost (bottom left) is calculated when all the items are loaded. Now the problem is, the items don't get loaded without scrolling. So the initial total is shown only for the top 2 items visible on screen.
How do I load all the items without having to scroll manually? I have tried auto scrolling but that doesn't work; it scrolls to the bottom but the total doesn't change.

[image]

Please know that its not just about the initial scrolling. Later the total keeps adding up as we scroll up and down. Now the calculation is being done in the onBindViewHolder which I know gets called every time we scroll. How do I avoid that?

I can provide all the code but I don't know which part to post...

```
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recvwCartList)


        val options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cart> = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Cart>()
            .setQuery(cartRef.child(currentUserPhone).child("Products"), Cart::class.java)
            .build()

        adapter =
            object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder>(options) {

                override fun onBindViewHolder(
                    holder: CartViewHolder,
                    position: Int,
                    model: Cart
                ) {


                    //initializations
                    imgbtnCartMinus = holder.ibCartMinus
                    imgbtnCartPlus = holder.ibCartPlus
                    txtvwCartTotalAmount = findViewById(R.id.txtvwCartTotalAmount)


                    //assigning values
                    holder.tvProductName.text = model.productName
                    holder.tvProductPrice.text =
                        resources.getString(R.string.rupee_symbol, model.price)

                    holder.tvCartProductQuantity.text = model.quantity
```

How am I supposed to get the total here?

Comment: This is a request contrary to the working principle. Why do you have such a request?

Comment: Using recyclerview for the first time. I din't know all this.

Comment: It will load when the new item is loaded with Recyclerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need to change the logic of your app that calculates the the total based on the scrolling because the user expects the entire value of the cart products, and RecyclerView as the name suggests keeps only the views which are visible and destorys and recreates the views when they go off the screen , in a way recycles them to prevent overuse of memory, so when you add the list of all products to your `RecylerView.Adapter` descendant you should add the cost of all the items too because the list of all items is already known before hand

Comment: Any idea how to do it with FirebaseRecyclerOptions?

Comment: @whoadityanawandar I am afraid, you can't do it with the `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` class because it was made just for generalized operations to reduce the boiler plate. The reason is that all the data fetching is handled by `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` itself and for your case, we will need the data before hand so make sure you fetch the data seperately and when you receive the data, you can update your adapter with `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: A normal `RecyclerView` with an `Adapter` is the most common thing which all the Android developers must know, so you should explore it. Just a suggestion

Comment: I had to change the logic and calculated the total in the onCreate before the adapter is set.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use FirebaseRecycleOptions , and if I suggest you to calculate the total sum of all the items and show it even if you do not scroll

Comment: How do I do that without FirebaseRecyclerOpitions?

Comment: yes you need FirebaseRecyclerOpitions. sorry but it is now that I see the code. Here is a github repo to help you calculate the amount before sending it to the recyclerview
https://github.com/OtnielaSolofo/sum_recyclerview.git

Comment: the key is that you should have all the data before sending it to the recycler view

Comment: Exactly my question; how do I have all the data before sending it to the recycler view?!
There's nothing in the library??!

Comment: you can retest because I have already done a push

Comment: Where is the model item list data coming from? You have hard coded it, how would I get it ?

Comment: you can replace the model with your data source. You should not do the sum calculation in the adapter

Answer (score 0):

You should poll your Firebase DB in advance once and calculate the total regardless of whats on the screen. This logic you're trying to do does not really make sense from a software engineer perspective.

I'd calculate the price on load, then recaculate on each new addittion or change and display that price (would probably hook this up via an Observable and Databinding). Your layout should not influence business logic at all.

Comment: I get the logic now, the problem is I don't know how to do that with FirebaseRecyclerOptions.

Comment: I think you need to check the Firebase DB documentation. I'm not that familiar with it to help, but this is not the class you need I believe. Per a google search this is a helper class to basically connect the DB and the UI. I think you need to query your DB in some other way.

Answer (score -1):

Any particular reason to calculate in the onBindViewHolder?
Total calculation should be runned when you got item list data.
It really looks not good having dependency with recyclerView.

Imagine theres no RecyclerView and change the calcuration logic